# What does leveling up do in Drakengard 3?

Tags: drakengard-3

In Drakengard 3, killing enemies earns experience to level up Zero. However, I can't find a stats screen to see how I've grown after leveling up. What does leveling up actually do?

[image: Experience bar for Zero]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/drakengard/comments/bzyqxz/what_does_player_level_actually_do_in_drakengard_3/):

> It boosts attack, defence and health.
> If you go to an earlier level when you have reached a higher player level, you'll see that the enemies and bosses are a lot easier to kill.